# Where to get SIFT_WEBHOOK_SECRET_KEY for your Sift Science decisions?

Tags: api, authentication, secret-key, fraud-prevention

I'm working on integrating back-end decisions based on the result of Sift Science's Workflows I followed [this](https://siftscience.com/developers/docs/python/decisions-api/decision-webhooks/authentication) decision webhook tutorial but I don't know where exactly to get the value of SIFT_WEBHOOK_SECRET_KEY. Has anyone done this successfully before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've gone back and answered this. In the sift console there is a developer tab. In it you find the SIFT_WEBHOOK_SECRET_KEY under the Signature Keys Section.

The view to generate a secret key looks like this:
[image]